# rsync succeeds from the shell but complains of "syntax or usage error" from crontab

Tags: cron, centos7, rsync

The following crontab line (on CentOS 7.6)

```
@daily rsync -rav --remove-source-files --files-from=<(find /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 -type f -mtime +30 -exec basename {} \;) /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 192.168.1.31:/local/raid0/buildbotpackages/packages/rhel7
```

fails, and sends me the following email message:

```
From: (Cron Daemon) <crontab@docker.local>
Subject: Cron <qa@docker> rsync -rav --remove-source-files --files-from=<(find /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 -type f -mtime +30 -exec basename {} \;) /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 192.168.1.31:/local/raid0/buildbotpackages/packages/rhel7


rsync: failed to open files-from file <(find /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 -type f -mtime +30 -exec basename {} ;): No such file or directory
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1567) [client=3.1.2]
```

I looked at the source code of rsync's main.c, but could not see the relevance of line 1567:

```
   1557     SIGACTMASK(SIGINT, sig_int);
   1558     SIGACTMASK(SIGHUP, sig_int);
   1559     SIGACTMASK(SIGTERM, sig_int);
   1560 #if defined HAVE_SIGACTION && HAVE_SIGPROCMASK
   1561     sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigmask, NULL);
   1562 #endif
   1563 
   1564     /* Ignore SIGPIPE; we consistently check error codes and will
   1565      * see the EPIPE. */
   1566     SIGACTION(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
   1567 #ifdef SIGXFSZ
   1568     SIGACTION(SIGXFSZ, SIG_IGN);
   1569 #endif
   1570 
   1571     /* Initialize change_dir() here because on some old systems getcwd
   1572      * (implemented by forking "pwd" and reading its output) doesn't
   1573      * work when there are other child processes.  Also, on all systems
   1574      * that implement getcwd that way "pwd" can't be found after chroot. */
   1575     change_dir(NULL, CD_NORMAL);
   1576 
   1577     init_flist();
```

Furthermore, when I run that exact crontab line from the shell, it works:

```
qa@docker /tmp$ rsync -rav --remove-source-files --files-from=<(find /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 -type f -mtime +30 -exec basename {} \;) /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 192.168.1.31:/local/raid0/buildbotpackages/packages/rhel7
sending incremental file list

sent 18 bytes  received 12 bytes  20.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
qa@docker /tmp$
```

Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

Comment: cron runs commands with `/bin/sh`, which won't support all the fancy syntax of your interactive shell. command substitution with `<(...)` is not a part of the standard `sh` language.

Comment: You could put the `rsync` command in a shell script (starting with a shebang line that specifies bash -- `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), and run the script from `cron`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Wumpus. If you put it in an answer, I could contribute to your StackOverflow reputation.

Comment: Just chipping in. Try replacing rsync with full path. Usually it is (/usr/bin/rsync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broken cron jobs are frequently caused by testing the command in a different shell from the one cron uses. Most of the popular interactive shells like `bash` and `zsh` and the standard `/bin/sh` (used by cron) have similar basic syntax, because they're all descended from the Bourne shell. The similarity between them is strong enough that you can get by, for a while, thinking that cron's command syntax is the same as your login shell.

When you put more complex commands into a crontab, you find that there are differences. In your example, I suspect the command substitution operator `<(...)`. This type of substitution didn't exist in Bourne shell, and I don't think POSIX has adopted it either, so I wouldn't trust it in a cron job.

Test your command in `/bin/sh` on your system by simply running one within your other shell:

```
BIG-FANCY-PROMPT%>$ sh
$ rsync -rav --remove-source-files --files-from=<(find /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 -type f -mtime +30 -exec basename {} \;) /home/qa/buildbot/master/packages/rhel7 192.168.1.31:/local/raid0/buildbotpackages/packages/rhel7
... probably some error message here...
$ exit
BIG-FANCY-PROMPT%>$ _
```

If you can't think of a way to rewrite the command in `sh` syntax, you can always explicitly invoke `bash` or any other shell you like:

```
@daily bash -c '...'
```

This way involves an extra layer of quoting so that `sh` will pass the whole command to `bash` without trying to parse it. If that becomes too difficult, then put your command in a script with a nice `#!` line and run *that* from cron.